# Visual Studio (2008) - Which projects reference a particular assembly?

Tags: visual-studio, assemblies, resharper, reference, projects-and-solutions

I have a solution with a decent number of projects (say, 30) and I want to find which of these projects reference a particular assembly.

Here's a concrete example: In the *Object Browser* I can see that two different versions of the same assembly are referenced throughout the solution. I want to see which project(s) use each of these references, so I can update them all to point to the same thing.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/bd7c85cb2e.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/bd7c85cb2e.png)

Unfortunately, the .csproj files are scattered in different locations, so a simple grep is not all that simple.

Any suggestions?

I'm thinking of making a script that parses the .sln file and then parse each project file, but maybe there's a simpler solution.

PS. I'm using ReSharper, if that's any help.

Comment: It's been over two hours since you posted this question.  Clicking through the 30 projects' Reference nodes should have taken half an hour, tops.  Probably about as long as writing a little utility that uses Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().

Comment: ...which is what I've done anyway :-) 
Problem is, I find myself doing this every once in a while, so writing an utility may pay up after all

Answer (score 1):

In Resharper 5.0, you can click on a project and use "Find Code Dependent on Module". That should give you what you want.

Comment: +1 Cool to know, but it doesn't work for external assemblies, like DevExpress